# Query to fetch only row for a person

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table xx_wr :

```
PERSON_NUM      ACTION_CODE       EFF_START_DATE    EFF_END_DATE
10               RE                01-JAN-2016        31-DEC-4712
12               TERM              02-FEB-2016         01-MAR-2016
12                RE               02-MAR-2016        31-DEC-4712
```

Ideally, when there is RE action code for a person, there should be a TERM action code record also. For eg : person number :12 
I am querying to fetch all the persons with only action_code as RE and no action code as TERM against the same person number. Eg : 10

```
SELECT *
FROM
  ( SELECT xx_WR.ACTION_CODE ACTION_CODE,
           ROW_NUMBER() over (partition BY PERSON_NUM
                              ORDER BY ACTION_CODE) AS rn
   FROM xx_WR ) T
WHERE RN =1
  AND ACTION_CODE='RE';
```

This query is returning 12 and 10. It should pick only 10 as we are fetching those person numbers with action_code as 'RE' and no 'TERM' row in this table.

Comment: can you share the expected result.

Comment: inner query using this one `SELECT xx_WR.ACTION_CODE ACTION_CODE,
           COUNT(*) over (partition BY PERSON_NUM) AS rn
   FROM xx_WR`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

querying to fetch all the persons with only action_code as RE and no action code as TERM against the same person number.

If I got your requirement, you can achieve this using not exists also.

```
SELECT *
FROM xx_WR  a
WHERE a.ACTION_CODE='RE'
AND not exists ( select 1
                 from xx_WR  b
                  where b.ACTION_CODE ='TERM'
                and  a.PERSON_NUM = b.PERSON_NUM)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want persons with a *single* `RE` action code, then use this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM xx_wr t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT PERSON_NUM
    FROM xx_wr
    GROUP BY PERSON_NUM
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) t2
    ON t1.PERSON_NUM = t2.PERSON_NUM
WHERE t1.ACTION_CODE = 'RE'
```

If you can also accept persons with *more* than one action code, so long as `TERM` does not appear against that person, then use this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM xx_wr t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT PERSON_NUM
    FROM xx_wr
    GROUP BY PERSON_NUM
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN ACTION_CODE = 'TERM' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 AND
           SUM(CASE WHEN ACTION_CODE = 'RE'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
) t2
    ON t1.PERSON_NUM = t2.PERSON_NUM
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
       SELECT
          *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_NUM, ACTION_CODE ORDER BY EFF_END_DATE DESC) as rn
          ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ACTION_CODE = 'RE' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_NUM) as RECount
          ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ACTION_CODE = 'TERM' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_NUM) as TERMCount
       FROM
          xx_WR
    ) t
WHERE
    t.rn = 1
    AND t.ACTION_CODE = 'RE'
    AND t.RECount > t.TERMCount
```

so `ROW_NUMBER()` does only that, it builds a row number. you actually are in need of comparing the number of `RE` records vs `TERM` records per `PERSON_NUM`.  Based on your description it sounded like you might be able to get a case such as `RE -> TERM -> RE` and that you would then want to have that one returned as well.  Anyway, the use of window functions here is great especially when you team with *Conditional Aggregation*.  Also note that this solution will handle the `RE -> RE` case and still return the latest RE record.

Note you can adapt if you want to find only the scenario where there is NO term record at all like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
       SELECT
          *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_NUM, ACTION_CODE ORDER BY EFF_END_DATE DESC) as rn
          ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ACTION_CODE = 'RE' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_NUM) as RECount
          ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ACTION_CODE = 'TERM' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_NUM) as TERMCount
       FROM
          xx_WR
    ) t
WHERE
    t.rn = 1
    AND t.ACTION_CODE = 'RE'
    AND t.TERMCount = 0
```

And if you only want someone with 1 RE record and no TERM you could just change the where clause slightly again or you also do not need the row number anymore either so you could do:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
       SELECT
          *
          ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ACTION_CODE = 'RE' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_NUM) as RECount
          ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ACTION_CODE = 'TERM' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_NUM) as TERMCount
       FROM
          xx_WR
    ) t
WHERE
    t.ACTION_CODE = 'RE'
    AND t.RECount = 1
    AND t.TERMCount = 0
```